# Trying to get RecyclerView to use a diffferent dataset

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to update the list that my RecyclerView is showing.

What I'm trying to do is show a subset of a shown list when a spinner is changed. I have a collection of animals in my database and some have their `pet` attribute set as `true` and others have it set as `false`.

Using Room Database with repositories and viewModels, and what I've been trying to piece together is that it's good to have three different lists that I can tune into, so in m

Repository:

```kotlin
class AnimalRepository(private val animalDao: AnimalDao) {
    val allAnimals: Flow<List<Animal>> = animalDao.getAnimalsByCategory()
    val pets: Flow<List<Animal>> = animalDao.getAnimalsByPetStatus(true)
    val nonPets: Flow<List<Animal>> = animalDao.getAnimalsByPetStatus(false)

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(animal: Animal) {
        animalDao.insert(animal)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun get(id: Int): Animal {
        return animalDao.get(id)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun delete(id: Int) {
        animalDao.delete(id)
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
class AnimalViewModel(private val repository: AnimalRepository) : ViewModel() {

    var allAnimals: LiveData<List<Animal>> = repository.allAnimals.asLiveData()
    val pets: LiveData<List<Animal>> = repository.pets.asLiveData()
    val nonPets: LiveData<List<Animal>> = repository.nonPets.asLiveData()
    var result: MutableLiveData<Animal> = MutableLiveData<Animal>()
    var mode: VIEW_MODES = VIEW_MODES.BOTH

    /*
    * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
    * */
    fun insert(animal: Animal) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(animal)
    }

    /*
    * Launching a new coroutine to get the data in a non-blocking way
    * */
    fun get(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        result.value = repository.get(id)
    }

    fun delete(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.delete(id)
    }
}

class AnimalViewModelFactory(private val repository: AnimalRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T: ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AnimalViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return AnimalViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity` I have it set up where I have an observer on these three lists and depending on which view mode is active (the spinner sets the view mode), that list is fed into the my RecyclerView's ListAdapter's submitList

```kotlin
animalViewModel.allAnimals.observe(this) { animals ->
    if (viewMode == VIEW_MODES.BOTH) {
        animals.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
            // recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
}
animalViewModel.pets.observe(this) { animals ->
    if (viewMode == VIEW_MODES.PETS) {
        animals.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
            // recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
}
animalViewModel.nonPets.observe(this) { animals ->
    if (viewMode == VIEW_MODES.NON_PETS) {
        animals.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I am changing the mode with my spinner doing

```kotlin
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            viewMode = VIEW_MODES.BOTH
        }
        1 -> {
            viewMode = VIEW_MODES.PETS
        }
        2 -> {
            viewMode = VIEW_MODES.NON_PETS
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

This works fine if add or remove an animal after changing the view mode since the observers fire and the correct one is allowed to populate the adapter, but the `notifyDataSetChanged()` isn't doing anything and I've been stuck on getting the adapter to update without having to add or remove from the lists

I also tried resetting the adapter in the observer but that didn't do anything either

I am extremely new to kotlin and android programming, and I'm sure that I'm going about this the wrong way, but is there a way force a list refresh?

---

**Update:**

I think I may have found a found a solution but I worry that it's hacky. In my ViewModel I am replacing the contents of my `allAnimals` with the filtered lists

```kotlin
    fun showBoth() {
        allAnimals = repository.allAnimals.asLiveData()
    }
    fun showPets() {
        allAnimals = repository.pets.asLiveData()
    }
    fun showNonPets() {
        allAnimals = repository.nonPets.asLiveData()
    }
```

and then in my main activity I changed my logic on when handling the spinner change to tell the view model to do its thing and then to remove the observer and slap it back on

```kotlin
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            animalViewModel.showBoth()
        }
        1 -> {
            animalViewModel.showPets()
        }
        2 -> {
            animalViewModel.showNonPets()
        }
    }
    refreshObserver()
}

private fun refreshObserver() {
    animalViewModel.allAnimals.removeObservers(this)
    animalViewModel.allAnimals.observe(this) { animals ->
        animals.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    }
}
```

this seems to work to get the recycler view to update, but is it hacky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it makes perfect sense that `notifyDataSetChanged` isn't doing anything, you don't submit any new data before that call. However I think what you're trying to do is to get the adapter to react to a change in `viewMode`.

If this is the case, I would recommend also having your `viewMode` as a `LiveData` object and then expose a single list for your adapter to observe, which changes depending on the `viewMode` selected.

The `Transformations.switchMap(LiveData<X>, Function<X, LiveData<Y>>)` method (or its equivalent Kotlin extension function) would probably do most of the work for you here. In summary it maps the values of one `LiveData` to another. So in your example, you could map your `viewMode` to one of the `allAnimals`, `pets` and `nonPets`.

Here is a simple pseudocode overview for some clarity:

```
AnimalViewModel {

    val allAnimals: LiveData<List<Animal>>
    val pets: LiveData<List<Animal>>
    val nonPets: LiveData<List<Animal>>

    val modes: MutableLiveData<VIEW_MODES>

    val listAnimals = modes.switchMap {
        when (it) {
            VIEW_MODES.BOTH -> allAnimals
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

```
fun onItemSelected {
    
    viewModel.onModeChanged(position)
}
```

```
viewModel.listAnimals.observe {

    adapter.submitList(it)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked out really well! I had to change the `onItemSelected` to use `animalViewModel.modes.value = ViewModes.fromInt(position)` but that makes sense, since you said it was meant to be pseudo code